# Scaling in VMWare Workstation Player 16?

Tags: virtual-machine, display, virtualization, vmware

I know Workstation Pro has scaling options, but there doesn’t appear to be any for Workstation Player. I’ve tried lowering my host resolution, but then the image is blurry. Is there a way to scale the guest display so it’s more like nearest neighbor filtering instead of blurry bilinear filtering?

Comment: I don't remember offhand how scaling is handled in Workstation Pro, but it's possible that even if Player doesn't provide UI to configure it that it might still honor the entries in the configuration files.

Comment: Is there a list of possible entries for the configuration files?

Comment: There is not an official list.  There are unofficial third-party lists (e.g. https://sanbarrow.com/vmx.html).  Personally I'd just install a trial version of Workstation Pro (possibly within a VM), try configuring scaling options, and seeing what changes.  If the scaling configuration is per-VM, then it'd almost certainly be stored in the VM's `.vmx` file.